# Find spcific words in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I look for a word in a data frame it shows me every entry containing those letters but I really want for it to show me that specific word. Can you help me out?

Here is and example:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ['ROL', 'ROVER','ROL','ROLLER','ROL','TROLLER','rol','rolter','nan'] ,'col2': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```
ROL = df[df['col1'].fillna(0).str.contains("ROL|rol",na=False)]
```

The output is something like this

[image: Fin]

but what i really wanted was something without those entries

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a full match, you need [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) not `str.contains`:

```
df[df.col1.isin(['ROL', 'rol'])]

  col1  col2
0  ROL     1
2  ROL     3
4  ROL     5
6  rol     7
```

Or you could also do:

```
df[df.col1.str.lower().isin(['rol'])]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Thats it!

Comment: `df[df.col1.str.lower().isin(['rol'])]` should get them anyways? Or you mean matching `rOl` or `Rol` @erfan

Comment: Yes, my bad, didn't refresh the page yet, so didn't see edit.